# How to clear recently opened Git branches in VSTS 2019

Tags: git, azure-devops, repository, visual-studio-2019, git-branch

**How do I clear/ remove history of recently opened Git Repository Branches in Visual Studio 2019?** I am daily working on multiple bug fixes, feature enhancements, hot fixes etc., So i will be creating multiple branches according to that.

Any git commands to run  or  settings under VSTS Tool Options can be changed ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For testing, try and:

- purge remote tracking branches which are no longer on the remote repository (because those fix branches have been merged since)
- remove local branches for those obsolete remote tracking branches
- remove local branches you are no longer actively using.

Then relaunch VSTS 2019, and see if its branch menu reflects your trimmed list of branches